# Docker containers on travis-ci

Tags: ruby, rspec, docker, travis-ci

I have a Dockerfile that I am attempting to test using RSpec, serverspec and docker-api. Locally (using boot2docker as I am on OS X) this works great and all my test pass, but on travis-ci none of the tests pass. My `.travis.yml` file is as such:

```
language: ruby
rvm:
  - "2.2.0"

sudo: required
cache: bundler

services:
  - docker

before_install:
  - docker build -t tomasbasham/nginx .
  - docker run -d -p 80:80 -p 443:443 --name nginx -v $(pwd)/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf tomasbasham/nginx

script: bundle exec rspec
```

Am I doing something noticeably wrong here? The repository I have created and is run on travis-ci is on [GitHub](https://github.com/tomasbasham/nginx). There may be something else amiss that I am unaware of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### tl;dr

A container MUST run its program in the foreground.

---

Your Dockerfile is the issue. From the [github repository](https://github.com/tomasbasham/nginx/blob/master/Dockerfile) you provided, the Dockerfile content is:

```
# Dockerfile for nginx with configurable persistent volumes

# Select nginx as the base image
FROM nginx
MAINTAINER Tomas Basham <me@tomasbasham.co.uk>

# Install net-tools
RUN apt-get update -q && \
    apt-get install -qy net-tools && \
    apt-get clean

# Mount configurable persistent volumes
VOLUME ["/etc/nginx/sites-enabled", "/etc/nginx/certs", "/etc/nginx/conf.d", "/var/log/nginx", "/var/www/html"]

# Expose both HTTP and HTTPS ports
EXPOSE 80 443

# ENTRYPOINT
ENTRYPOINT ["service", "nginx", "start"]
```

Before debugging your RSpec/serverspec tests, you should make sure that docker image is able to run a container.

Type those commands from the directory which has the `Dockerfile` in:

```
docker build -t tmp .
docker run --rm -it tmp
```

If you get your shell prompt back to you, that means your container stopped running. If your container isn't starting, then your test suite will fail.

---

### What's wrong with the dockerfile

The entrypoint you defined `ENTRYPOINT ["service", "nginx", "start"]` will execute a command that will, in turn, start the *nginx* program in the **background**. This means the process that was initially run by docker (`/bin/service`) will terminate, and docker will detect that and stop your container.

To run nginx in the **foreground**, one must run `nginx -g daemon off;` as you can find in the [Dockerfile for the official nginx image](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/7f3ef0927ec619d20181e677c97f991df0d7d446/Dockerfile#L22). But since you put `daemon off;` in your *nginx.conf* file, you should be fine with just `nginx`.

I suggest you remove the entrypoint from your Dockerfile *(and also remove the `daemon off;` from your nginx config)* and it should work fine.

---

### serverspec

Once you get a container which runs, you will have to focus on the serverspec part on which I'm not experienced with.